# How to send POST request with JSON data to external database for login app in IOS using Swift?

Tags: json, swift, xcode7, ios9.3

I am new in Swift and iOS. Please send me the sample code for `POST` request with `JSON` data to external database for login app in iOS using Swift

Comment: you want to say how to parse JSON data with using swift language??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call post api like below code,

Try this

```
func callPostApi()
{
    let baseUrl : NSString = NSString(format: "YOUR_BASE_URL")   //"http://at.webby.com/php.api"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: baseUrl as String)!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let stringPost = "username=test&password=12345" // Key and Value param as string

    let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request.timeoutInterval = 60
    request.HTTPBody=data

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        let err1: NSError? = nil
        do
        {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            print(json)
        }
        catch
        {
            print(err1)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

class ViewController: UIViewController  {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

var arrData = NSArray()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    postAPICall()
}

func postAPICall() {

    let urlString = "http://18.220.215.90/backend/web/index.php/site/getstylistlist"

    let dictParameter = ["Salon_Latitude": "23.0387822",
                    "Register_User_ID": "0",
                    "page": "0",
                    "Filter_Keyword": "",
                    "Register_User_Year_Of_Experience": "0",
                    "Salon_Longitude": "72.514567",
                    "pagesize": "20",
                    "api_type": "iphone",
                    "Register_User_Login_ID": "0",
                    "Cost": "0",
                    "Version": "1",
                    "api_userid": "",
                    "Distance_KM": "",
                    "Register_User_Professional_Sub_Type": "All"
                     ]




    let param = JsonStringFromDictionary(parameter: dictParameter as AnyObject, type: "json")
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse!) in
    switch response.result{

    case.success:

        print("Sucess")

        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            self.arrData = JSON as! NSArray

            print(self.arrData)

        }

    case.failure(let Error):
        print("error\(Error)")

}
```

}
}